# How to get list of azure container images which are affected after security scans?

Tags: linux, azure

I know how to get repositories, we can use
`az acr repository list --name myregistry`.

But, how to get repositories with tags that are having security/vulnerability issues after security scans using azure cli?

Answer (score 0):

I thinks what you talking about it log level.

Maybe find more information in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerregistry/registries/connectedregistries?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template